# How do I insert datetime value into a SQLite database?

Tags: sql, datetime, sqlite

I am trying to insert a datetime value into a [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database. It seems to be sucsessful but when I try to retrieve the value there is an error:

> <Unable to read data>

The SQL statements are:

```
create table myTable (name varchar(25), myDate DATETIME)
insert into myTable (name,mydate) Values ('fred','jan 1 2009 13:22:15')
```

Answer (score 175, accepted):

The format you need is:

```
'2007-01-01 10:00:00'
```

i.e. yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

If possible, however, use a parameterised query as this frees you from worrying about the formatting details.

Comment: How does one order by date with such strings?

Comment: When you format dates like this, date ordering and lexical ordering work out the same. E.g. '2008-02-01' > '2007-02-01', '2008-01-02' > '2008-01-01' both as strings and as dates.  But you don't strictly need to care about this because SQLite ORDER BY will take care of ordering for you.

Comment: Note that you can't reliably compare dates with different precision using lexical ordering, e.g "SELECT '2007-01-02 10:00:00' > '2007-01-02 10:00';" returns 1 but "SELECT datetime('2007-01-02 10:00:00') > datetime('2007-01-02 10:00');" returns 0.

Comment: @itowlson How will this work when you have multi lingual application?

Answer (score 50):

The way to store dates in SQLite is:

```
 yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.xxxxxx
```

SQLite also has some date and time functions you can use. See [SQL As Understood By SQLite, Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: FYI, `.xxxxxx` here in @TorValamo's syntax = `.SSS` = %f in the SQLite documentation, i.e. fractional seconds.

Comment: DateTime.parse('2016-05-28 14:27:00 -0300').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Answer (score 18):

You have to change the format of the date string you are supplying in order to be able to insert it using the STRFTIME function.  Reason being, there is no option for a month abbreviation:

```
%d  day of month: 00
%f  fractional seconds: SS.SSS
%H  hour: 00-24
%j  day of year: 001-366
%J  Julian day number
%m  month: 01-12
%M  minute: 00-59
%s  seconds since 1970-01-01
%S  seconds: 00-59
%w  day of week 0-6 with sunday==0
%W  week of year: 00-53
%Y  year: 0000-9999
%%  %
```

The alternative is to format the date/time into an already accepted format:

1. YYYY-MM-DD
2. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
3. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
4. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
5. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
6. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
7. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
8. HH:MM
9. HH:MM:SS
10. HH:MM:SS.SSS
11. now

Reference: [SQLite Date & Time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: Although not listed in the table the docs also state that you may add 'Z' or offsets such as '-0400'

Answer (score 15):

Use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` when you need it, instead OF `NOW()` (which is MySQL)

Comment: this is worked, one thing is wrong. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP return datetime without UTC, do you know how to resolve this problem. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

Read [This](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html): 1.2 `Date` and Time Datatype
best data type to store date and time is:

`TEXT` best format is: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Then read [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) page; this is best explain about date and time in `SQLite`.
I hope this help you

Comment: You should consider answer the question, with links that support your answer, not just a bunch of links

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most popular or efficient method, but I tend to forgo strong datatypes in [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) since they are all essentially dumped in as strings anyway.

I've written a thin C# wrapper around the SQLite library before (when using SQLite with C#, of course) to handle insertions and extractions to and from SQLite as if I were dealing with DateTime objects.

Comment: Doesn't cut it for dates if e.g. you wanted to sort by that field; you end up with a string comparison...