# Date format in android 11 Oct 2012 15:40

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to insert date in below format in sqlite through android:

11 Oct 2012 15:40

Please help me how to achieve this??

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933720/how-do-i-insert-datetime-value-into-a-sqlite-database it may help you

Comment: What is even the datatype in schema you want to insert to? if it's a datetime, that format will have to be specified to the query engine, if it's varchar then I guess you are free to store whatever you want :)

Comment: Thanks for your help I have resolved it with this SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
// date is Object of Date class of java.util
String s = formatter.format(date);
// now you can save 's' to the sqlite.
```