# Designing SQLite Database without Date format

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, database-design

I am trying to store Date in sqlite database in android mm/dd/yyyy , I have read about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933720/how-do-i-insert-datetime-value-into-a-sqlite-database) 
What happens if I don't have `HH:mm:ss` (which is not needed for my application)?. 
Is avoiding the date format of database by splitting it up a method used in the industry? ex:

```
Db Columns:
_id INTEGER;
data TEXT;
day INTEGER;
month INTEGER;
year INTEGER;
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What do you want to do with the Date in the DB? I had some problems storing such dates in an mysql db with HH:mm:ss = 00:00:00. I woud consider to store it as String yyyyMMdd (this still keeps the correct order for sorting)

Comment: Show it in user interface, and comparing operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the Date in milliseconds. Then build the appropriate format according the user's Locale at run time.

Answer (score 0):

If you wand to use ony little memory, consider to store ddMMyyyy in a single `int`variable.

either easy to read in logoutput

```
day+month*100+year*10000
```

day, month year can be extracted by devision and modulo operations

or for faster to handle for the computer

```
day&0x1F+(month<<5)&0xF+(year<<9)
```

day, month year can be extracted by `>>` and `&` and operations

Comment: In both cases the 'before' and 'after' relation is mapped to '<' and '>'

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility reasons, my app stores dates as strings, in ISO "YYYY-MM-DD" format. This is a special case though. For most purposes, Sam is the man.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite's date functions also understand date strings in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Splitting up dates into their three fields is possible, but then you will not be able to easily do computations on them.