# SQLiteDatabase add date into database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, datetime

I have a class extends SQLiteOpenHelper and a database declared as:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_TEMPERATURA
            + " TEXT, " + COL_UMIDITA + " TEXT," + COL_DATA + "DATETIME)");
}
```

now i would insert records inside it, but when i try to insert the last field (of DATETIME type) eclipse told me that i can't do it:

```
public void insertRecord(List<Object[]> list) throws ParseException {
    String temperatura, umidita, data;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        temperatura = String.valueOf(list.get(i)[0]);
        umidita = String.valueOf(list.get(i)[1]);
        data = String.valueOf(list.get(i)[2]);
        // parsing data
        DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date data_date = dateformat.parse(data);
        // insert into database
        cv.put(COL_TEMPERATURA, temperatura);
        cv.put(COL_UMIDITA, umidita);
        cv.put(COL_DATA, data_date);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        db.close();
    }
```

because cv.put() takes as arguments only two strings. Now if i parse data_date variable into string, MySql automatically convert it in its correct format?

Comment: SQLite doesnt have a DATETIME format: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html - instead try the following date scheme: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933720/how-do-i-insert-datetime-value-into-a-sqlite-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite doesnt support DateTime format. Instead, i recommend you to use string in ISO8601 format:

```
"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"
```

Read more about it [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Using this format of course supports ordering. I prefer this string format, because its much more readable. If you choose integer format (number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01) you will not get the same readability without parsing involved...

Comment: subsequently i perform a select query on database, and i need records ordered ascending by date. If i store date in this ISO format, could i have issue with that query?

Comment: @giozh just save the date as a timestamp, it will be much easier to deal with

Comment: @tyczj i dont see how using timestamp will be easier to deal with than ISO8601 string.

Comment: @giozh of course you can order by date when you use this format. Simply use ORDER BY as you would on any other column, it will work.  See edited answer.

Comment: @giozh its easier because you have just a number and not a formatted date and you dont have to worry about timezone issues when storing

Answer (score 3):

you cannot insert objects into SQLite you can only enter `Integers`, `Text`, `Blobs`, `Real` or `Numeric`

so you need to send the date in as a string or better yet make the date as a timestamp and store the timestamp so its easier to process stuff