# Issue with NULL values in date column using strftime function in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, null, strftime

I am working with a SQLite database that includes a column with dates in the format "YYYY-MM-DD". I am trying to extract the year and month from each date using the strftime function, but for these rows "2021-02-14 6:37:00", "2021-02-19 3:35:00" the function returns NULL.

I tried to check if SELECT from this column shows all rows. And it shows all dates correctly. I would like to know why NULL appears

Comment: Please include the sample data directly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

> Date and time values can be stored as text in a subset of the **ISO-8601** format, numbers representing the
> Julian day, or numbers representing the number of seconds since (or
> before) 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (the unix timestamp).

[ISO 8601 format - wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

> Each date and time value has a fixed number of digits that **must be
> padded with leading zeros**.

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/wCn4a8ZI) for values with and without leading zeros.

Comment: Thank you, it was usefull, I think the problem os with missing zeros before hours!

Comment: Yes, missing zeros caused an error. Also please read: [How do I insert datetime value into a SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933720/how-do-i-insert-datetime-value-into-a-sqlite-database).